# How to check NAT live?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump, nat, troubleshooting

I'm doing some troubleshooting in our network and VPNs and I want to monitor the traffic and I want to see if the SNAT and DNAT is working fine.
I want something live like tcpdump that I can see something like:

192.168.25.40 <----> 172.16.30.245 icmp echo-request 194.30.25.10
194.30.25.10 icmp echo-reply 172.26.30.245 <----> 192.168.25.40

Is it possible to do it with tcpdump, or iptraf or iftop ? Or is there any other tool I could use to see the NAT in real time ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible with `tcpdump`. Monitor both the incoming and the outgoing IF, and you should see the differents IPs. If there's a lot of other traffic at the same time which you can't stop, a better alternative is `wireshark`, because it has a GUI and filters.

Comment: I checked the interfaces but it shows only the ip i'm pinging and the IP of the NAT. It doesn't show the IP before the NAT. Do I need any specific parameter ? I've used -vvvv to see the most information but still not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing wrong, but here's an example. Setup: Two network namespaces `ns0` and `ns1` with two `veth` pairs, main namespace forwards:

```
ns0          <------- main ------->     ns1
veth0b   --- veth0a          veth1a --- veth1b
10.0.0.1     10.0.0.254  10.0.1.254     10.0.1.1
```

Doing plain `tcpdump` on `veth0a` and `veth1a`. Pinging `ns0` from `ns1` without NAT shows:

```
IP 10.0.1.1 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 20765, seq 1, length 64
IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 20765, seq 1, length 64
```

on `veth0a`, and on `veth1a`:

```
IP 10.0.1.1 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 20765, seq 1, length 64
IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 20765, seq 1, length 64
```

After enableing SNAT on `veth0a` with

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o veth0a -s 10.0.1.1/32 -j SNAT --to 10.0.1.90
```

now on `veth0a` there is

```
IP 10.0.1.90 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 20795, seq 1, length 64
IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.1.90: ICMP echo reply, id 20795, seq 1, length 64
```

while on `veth1a`

```
IP 10.0.1.1 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 20795, seq 1, length 64
IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 20795, seq 1, length 64
```

So one can clearly see the SNAT is working.

As I said, you need to dump packets on **both** the outgoing and the incoming interface.

Comment: I see. You are checking them both at the same time. Makes sense. I wanted to know if there was a way to see it with only one to see all outgoing traffic being nated and their origins since my network has a /22 subnet with ips going from 192.168.20 to 192.168.25 sort of thing.

Comment: No, you can't check on the same IF before and after NAT. What's the problem with checking both IFs? You'll be doing the pings manually, anyway. And if SNAT works for one IP, it will likely also work for the others.

Comment: And if you really need to identify pings, use `ping -p` with some pattern. But it's quite obvious what's going on if you have two xterms with `tcpdump` open.